# Teradata Client 3.1, EF Core 3.1, Connection / Session Lives On

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, teradata

I'm having trouble finding specific documentation around manually ending the session via .exit or .quit or if its even possible with FromSqlRaw.

**Problem Statement:**

On connect and execution of a stored procedure a Teradata session is created. After destruction of the db context the session appears to live on for some unknown amount of time. Restarting the service clears it immediately.

Attempts to manually end the session via .exit fail.

**Examples:**

With dependency injection:

```
services.AddDbContext<TeradataContext>(options => 
    options.UseTeradata(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EDW"), opts => {
        opts.CommandTimeout(120);
    })
 );
```

It's my understanding connection pooling would not happen as it is lifecycle and not added as a pool. But since garbage collection could take some time I decided to try moving it as a test:

```
 using (var dbContext = new TeradataContext())
 {         
     int result = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CALL .... ({0});", bar);
     dbContext.Database.CloseConnection();
 }
```

The session on Teradata still persists and the next call fails as the stored procedure fails to create the already existing volatile table.

I tried adding:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(".exit");
```

I get back:

> [Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between ';' and '.'.

Does anyone know the correct way to call .exit here? Or any other way to force the close and end of session using Teradata Client 3.1,   EF Core 3.1

```
dbContext.Database.CloseConnection();
```

But the session still persists so I don't believe their provider is performing a quit or exit.

I am not every experienced with TeraData...

I was really hoping to use EF but I guess I could fall back to other options if we can't figure this out.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: WIth EF (and any database), don't you need to `Dispose` the context to actually close the session?

Comment: The using statement should Dispose of it as far as I understand it.

Comment: Per Teradata's documentation, Connection Pooling property is True by default with 60 second timeout. Does your connection string set it to False?

Comment: You're spot on, I had wrongly assumed that with it turned off things would work as intended but every query is now ending the TD session and losing volatile tables. I cannot seem to get EF Core to use the same connection in the same session. Instead I can set the max pool size to 1 and idle life time to 1 and hope for the best... or just handle connections myself and test that. Thank you for your input!